# Wordpress SQl error

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to query the database and to pull some results trough Wordpress admin interface.

```
// Turn error echoing on
$wpdb->show_errors();

// Prepare the query for safety
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id, city, state, title, desc, price
                         FROM list WHERE city = %s AND state = %s"
                        ,$city, $state);

$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);

if (!$result)
{
    // Database error! Print it and leave the function
    echo $wpdb->print_error();
    return;
}
```

This is part of the code from the function. $city and $state are passed as parameters.
Anyway the error I'm getting when reloading the page is:

```
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
use near 'desc, price FROM list WHERE city = 'Los Angeles' AN' at line 1]
SELECT id, city, state, title, desc, price FROM list
WHERE city = 'Los Angeles' AND    state = 'CA'
```

The problem is in the desc name of the column, I mean in the name desc as far as was able to see.
Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: `desc` is reserved word from mysql try with backticks `\`desc\``

Comment: I can't believe i forgout about that. Script works now. Thank you Rahil.